# How to center a non-symmetrical object on the X axis xith a python script?

Tags: python, scripting

Here is my non-symmetrical object : [image]

As you can see the left part (X negative, the black line) is not egal to the right part (X positive, red line).
How can I get equal parts by translating my object with a python script ?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to find the extreme values on x axis and calculate where should be the center :

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
max = -9999
min = 9999
for i in obj.data.vertices :
    if i.co[0] > max :
        max_ind = i.index
        max  = i.co[0]
    if i.co[0] < min :
        min_ind = i.index
        min  = i.co[0]

shift = (max-min)/2 - max
obj.location[0] +=shift
```

Comment: @reflyon you're welcome,  the object should be centered like in the image ,because  I forget to convert to world coordinates, i'll edit !

Answer (score 0):

First set your object origin to center of bounding box, then move it to the location you want.

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY', center='BOUNDS')
bpy.context.object.location.x = 0
```